# Symfony3 - How to separate radio buttons from a choicetype

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig, symfony

I would like to create a text field with a radio button (input group) and a single radio button above that field. I want the 2 radio buttons to be linked.

Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/y8tecoyf/

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Field 1 :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 ">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" aria-label="..." name="choice" value="f1">
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Field 2 :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 ">
    <input type="radio" aria-label="..." name="choice" value="f2">
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to do that since the radio buttons in a choicetype can't be manipulated link distinct fields. Or can I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your Symfony form class with two fields (the text field + your choice field).

```
$builder->add('choiceField', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => [your choices]
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false
));
$builder->add('textField')
```

In your template, you need to split the rendering of the `choiceField` field. You can either:

1. use straight HTML as you have in your example, making sure you use the `name` attribute expected by the Symfony form system to ensure validation works
2. use the Symfony form rendering where appropriate, as follows:

   ```
   {{ form_widget(form.choiceField[0]) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.textField) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.choiceField[1]) }}
   ```

Method 2 is the preferred one as it will take care of form repopulation.

Comment: Well, I must say, that hit the spot, I didn't know I could separate choicefields that easily. Thanks a lot !